# NTP no server suitable

Tags: ntp

I have been trying with a lot of configuration, following different tips, but I can't get it to synchronize with a server:

```
ntpdate -u 192.168.1.100
3 Oct 01:01:13 ntpdate[11170]: no server suitable for synchronization found
```

And here is how it ended my ntp.conf:

```
driftfile /var/lib/ntp/drift
restrict default kod nomodify notrap nopeer noquery
restrict -6 default kod nomodify notrap nopeer noquery
restrict 127.0.0.1
restrict -6 ::1
server 172.16.1.1 iburst
server 0.us.pool.ntp.org
includefile /etc/ntp/crypto/pw
keys /etc/ntp/keys
```

I have been changing from different server pools, but there isn't any answer from anyone...

```
ntpq -c peers
remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
172.16.1.1      .INIT.          16 u    -   64    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
xanadu.fnerk.or .INIT.          16 u    -   64    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
```

Someone has a solution for this connection failure, pools used from:

http://www.pool.ntp.org/zone

Answer (score 3):

You did not instruct `ntpd` to reply to 192.168.1.100. I suppose you have a class `C` network, so add the following to your `ntp.conf`:

```
restrict 192.168.1.0 mask 255.255.255.0 nomodify notrap
```

Then reload `ntpd`. All should be set.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, but I did the same configuration on another PC. It worked, and I guess that also you have to look after the port if it is available where you're working, but that was a possible solution. Also, since I wasn't working from a full mint PC, I was missing some of the basic drivers.